# React or Angular 2 for server-side pre-rendering?

Tags: javascript, angular, reactjs

I am developing a web application that uses a Node.js backend API, and am thinking of using a framework like Angular or React. It is, however, important that there is not too much hassle involved in setting up reliable server-side rendering (for SEO purposes, among others).

I have found mixed information about the availability and ease of use of server-side rendering in both Angular 2 and React. Can someone clarify and give pointers as to which of these frameworks would be worth gaining a more thorough knowledge of at this time with these requirements?

Just to be clear, I'm talking about the initial page being rendered on the server and the client-side framework then taking over. This is beneficial for SEO and perceived performance among other things.

Comment: Your title is a bit confusing in my opinion. At first, I thought you'll like to use React or Angular as backend oO. Anyway, I read long time ago (about 4-5 months, maybe things changed) that React package is lightweight compared to Angular one. So in theory, it should render faster. But, you don't have all Angular's functionality and you'll probably add third party packages which will make the whole heavier

Comment: Some benchmarks : https://auth0.com/blog/more-benchmarks-virtual-dom-vs-angular-12-vs-mithril-js-vs-the-rest/ Some (biased?) review https://medium.freecodecamp.com/angular-2-versus-react-there-will-be-blood-66595faafd51#.evvkiicem

Answer (score 1):

Hmm. Instrestingly this question shouldnt have come if you have done enough reading.

React and Angular are leading frontend techonologies (no doubt). The question lies what should you use. You should probably ask yourself which tecnology am i comfortable with.

I started with React, but i wasnt comfortable and shifted to Anguar and now Angular2 but that doesnt mean React is not a dynamic language it is but it didnt fit me and my experience.

So probably try playing with both, and see with what you feel more confortable. You may also want to look at how their documentation is. Because it plays a very important role during the development.

Lastly, any front end languages can fit nodeJS.

Hope this gives you some idea or knowledge. However, everyone has their own point of view and you may get more confused. So rather go with your comfort level. I think you can even use nodejs to do rendering.

Comment: Why do you think this question "shouldn't have come up"? I'm talking about server-side pre-rendering and which framework would be best-suited for it.

Comment: Because is solely depends on you. Which you want to use.